# Se repiten los valores de un arraylist

Tags: java, mysql

bueno el problema es el siguiente; estoy haciendo un programa que tiene una base de datos y quiero hacer que regrese una consulta en una lista hecha con una clase de acceso (getter y setter)... pero al momento de ver la lista que me regresa la función me regresa la cantidad de consultas pero todas tienen la misma información de la ultima consulta.

Este es el codigo:

```
try{ 
        if (reporte=='g'){

            try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(aSQL);

            while (rs.next()) {
             int i=0;

              dtsGe.setCodigo(rs.getString("codigo"));
              dtsGe.setDescripcion(rs.getString("descripcion"));
              dtsGe.setCategoria(rs.getString("categoria"));

              dtsGe.setCod_interno(rs.getString("codigo_interno"));
              dtsGe.setNota(rs.getString("nota"));

              dtsGe.setLote(rs.getInt("lote"));
              dtsGe.setF_vencimiento(rs.getDate("f_vencimiento")); 
              dtsGe.setF_entrada(rs.getDate("f_entrada"));
              dtsGe.setProveedor(rs.getString("proveedor"));
              dtsGe.setDoc_entrada(rs.getString("doc_entrada"));
              dtsGe.setF_entrada(rs.getDate("f_docentrada"));
              dtsGe.setPrec_compra(rs.getDouble("prec_compra"));

              dtsGe.setF_salida(rs.getDate("f_salida"));
              dtsGe.setCliente(rs.getString("cliente"));
              dtsGe.setDoc_salida(rs.getString("doc_salida"));
              dtsGe.setF_salida(rs.getDate("f_docsalida"));
              dtsGe.setPrec_venta(rs.getDouble("prec_venta"));

              dtsGe.setNom_envio(rs.getString("nom_envio"));
              dtsGe.setCod_guia(rs.getString("cod_guia"));
              dtsGe.setF_entrega(rs.getDate("f_entrega"));
              dtsGe.setF_aprobado(rs.getDate("f_aprobado"));
              dtsGe.setF_devolucion(rs.getDate("f_devolucion"));
              dtsGe.setF_garantia(rs.getDate("f_garantia"));
              dtsGe.setMotivo(rs.getString("motivo"));
              dtsGe.setNota2(rs.getString("nota2"));

              lista.add(i,dtsGe);
              System.out.println(lista.get(i).getCod_interno());
              i++;
            }

            System.out.println(lista.get(10).getCod_interno());
            return lista;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
        }
```

En sí este es la parte interesante ya que el mismo problema se repite en métodos parecidos el primer Print me muestra todo los códigos únicos de los productos, ahí la lista está bien, pero en el segundo Print al querer ver el codigo de cualquier producto (en el ejemplo el 10) me sale solo el del ultimo...

No sé que estoy haciendo mal :C, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Estás *agregando* la misma referencia a la lista, por lo que todas *apuntan* a la misma  instancia. Necesitas crear cada vez una instancia de esa *clase de acceso*. En realidad, es un [POJO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object "Plain Old Java Object").

Comment: Paul Vargas tienes razón... me siento tan tonto :c, yo me imaginé que era una tontería, pero no que lo fuera tanto y llevo toda la tarde haciendo todo tipo de cosas... Muchas gracias :D

Comment: No te preocupes. :D Incluso los más experimentados pueden distraerse. :/ Sobretodo si estás en un estado de privación de cafeína. ☕

Comment: Yo lo detecté y no tengo cafeína en la sangre @PaulVargas y es casi 1 am :P

Comment: @PaulVargas fuera de bromas, sería mejor que publiques una respuesta al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

dentro del while crea una nueva intancia del objeto dtsGe

```
while(rs.next()){
  miClase dtsGe = new miClase();
  //aqui seteas los valores a tu clase

 //al final agregas ese objeto a tu lista
 lista.add(dtsGe);


}
```